# Asp.core 2 to get claims of curent user

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I may get claims using DI in asp.core1, as in the below

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;

    public UserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {           
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
}
```

In case with In asp.core 2, `_httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` has the value `false`, and doesn't contain claims.

My startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // ...
            };
        });

    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor();
}
```